# Will removing a MovieClip class remove the eventListeners inside it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript, event-listener

So, I have a class (called class A) that adds a child of a MovieClip class (both an object from the library, and a .as-file). Class A will remove and add this class a lot of times, so I donät want to be haning around with a bunch of Listeners that doesn't do anything.

I want to listens for clicks on the MovieClip, so I figured there are at least tree ways of doing this:

1. Add and remove an EventListener in class A at the same time you add/remove child.
2. Add the EventListener (to listen for clicks on itself) in the MovieClip class as-file.
3. Add an eventlistener inside the MovieClip (that's in the library).

So, my questions are:

1. Which one of the methods above is the best, and why?
2. Do you have to remove the eventListener in alternative 1 above? It's good practice, right?
3. Important question: Do I create a new Eventlistener every time I add the MovieClip class, if I've written the code like in alternative 2 above? And/Or will the EventListener be removed when the class is removed from Class A?

Would be really nice if someone could answer these questions clearly, one at a time, so I can make up my head. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you have to click on SOMETHING visual in your library MovieClip, and since your 'MovieClip class as-file' controls the library MovieClip, then you clearly want your listener function in the .as file.

2 and 3. I think that you're saying that you will be adding and removing your MovieClip multiple times, from class A. Your MovieClip's .as file should have, besides the CLICK-event listener that you're talking about, two other event-listener functions -- one that fires when there's an ADDED_TO_STAGE event, and another that listens for a REMOVED_FROM_STAGE event. These two will add and remove your CLICK listener whenever your MovieClip, itself, is added or removed from the display list.

So in the MovieClip's constructor say this: `addEventListener(Event,ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAddedToStage,false,0,true);`

In the 'onAddedToStage' function say:
`addEventListener(Event,REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,onRemovedFromStage;` 
And then add your CLICK listener.

In the 'onRemovedFromStage' function: Remove both the REMOVED_FROM_STAGE listener and your CLICK listener.

The only listener that is not removed by code is the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener, but because you created a weak reference to it (the 'true' in the ’addEventListener' line that registers it), it will eventually be garbage-collected if your MovieClip is no longer needed.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but... Okey, that is smart! Thanks.
Never been using that kind of event-listener before. Follow-up question: If I add a class (from my Main class) that adds a lot of movieclips to the stage (frame 1). And then I go to another frame and will probably not come back to frame 1. How important is it to remove the first class? And do I have to remove all the movieclips inside of that class as well, or are they automatically removed when I remove my class (via removeChild from Main class)?

Comment: Ok, first of all (and this is more than just a technicality) you don’t “remove the … class.” You remove the MovieClip object that was instantiated from the class. Second, you can remove it from the display list  ( with removeChild() ), but it’ll still exist in memory, as an instance of it’s class, until it’s garbage-collected. Or not! If you really want it to go away you have to remove all references to it (i.e. set them = null), and nullify itself as well. Flash will eventually garbage-collect it and it will truly be gone.

Comment: ...continued...    The MovieClip’s children will be automatically garbage collected when their parent is.  There's more to learn about all of this. For instance: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html